# Play Media Files from a Phone Over WiFi Network

Tags: android, sockets, http, streaming, media

How do I create a media server on android phone. I have all media files on one phone which will run as server and other devices should be able to play media form that devices. Like streaming form server, but here the server is android phone.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can wowza media streaming for that. This provides you streaming of live video from the mobile device over any network to any pc or other mobile device

Comment: that is for camera... i have a video file .. i have another device which is requesting that file using socket. currently i am sending the file that the client is downloading it and playing it. what i want to do is create a way that the client is able to stream is directly form the my device. is it possible using sockets

Comment: and there is no internet. its all wifi lan

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @MiladYarmohammadi yes  made it working, used live streaming protocol , used phone as server and other phone can connect and play.